# Setting Up vSphere ESXi 5.1 with two linux VMs

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I am trying to setup ESXi in a server and I am a bit lost. I have read lot's of documentation/serverfault.com/forums and guides.

There you go:

- Have a server with ESXi 5.1 installed
- Need initialially to create two linux VMs
- Got an idea about vSwitch behaviour and configuration.
- Have two static internet IP addresses provided by my host.

  1) I understand the ESXi must have one of these IPs assigned to it.

  2) The VMs can have any IP address (192.168.0.1/2 ??) and should have subnet mask (255.255.255.0)?

  3) I saw some guides on how to fowarding ports from the ESXi server to a VM. Is it the only way to configured? For example I can't have one of my VMs with my other static IP address exposed directly to the external world?

  4) Gateway: I have no idea. Should I configure the IP of the ESXi machine? Or the router/default gateway provided by my ISP?

  5) The ESXi at the moment have one of the static IPs assigned, but when I look at the uplink NIC in the networking configuration, it shows a completely different IP. Wasn't it supposed to be the same as the machine/ESXi server?

I think that with some light in these points I will be able to connect the dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2) The VMs can have any IP address (192.168.0.1/2 ??) and should have subnet mask (255.255.255.0)?

I'm not sure if this is a question or not, but if you have a private vSwitch, you can assign them RFC1918 addresses and NAT their outbound traffic through an additional VM if you want.

> 3) I saw some guides on how to fowarding ports from the ESXi server to a VM. Is it the only way to configured? For example I can't have one of my VMs with my other static IP address exposed directly to the external world?

No you didn't, you can't do this. You'd need something like an additional VM active as a reverse proxy. You can't have the management interface "shared" in this manner, so you'll have to share your second IP.

> 4) Gateway: I have no idea. Should I configure the IP of the ESXi machine? Or the router/default gateway provided by my ISP?

The management interface of your ESXi machine isn't doing any routing, why would you configure that as your gateway? Treat these machines like physical machines and set your gateway accordingly.

> 5) The ESXi at the moment have one of the static IPs assigned, but when I look at the uplink NIC in the networking configuration, it shows a completely different IP. Wasn't it supposed to be the same as the machine/ESXi server?

This doesn't make any sense. I'm not sure we can help you with something as basic as this.

---

You really don't need our help, you need a book on vSphere. I recommend Mastering VMWare vSphere 5 by Scott Lowe.

Comment: Or just some basic training in fact - we don't let anyone on our VMWare environments without at least them going through 'Install, Manage and Configure'.